# ConstraintLayout isn't rendering properly

Tags: java, android, xml

So I'm trying to make my score keeper app // No errors in the compiler

Here is a pictures of how it suppose to be / and how is coming out

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOqUb.jpg

All these images are actually buttons, here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                    


xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.android.leagueoflegendsscorekeeper.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/lol"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgViewMainBackground"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,MissingConstraints"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="104dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ribbonred"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="167dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgRibbonTeamAScore" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ribbonred"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="331dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="44dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgRibbonTeamAScoreDrake" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ribbonred"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="487dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="44dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgRibbonTeamAScoreBaron" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/zzz"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="487dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="271dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgRibbonTeamBScoreBaron" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/zzz"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="333dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="269dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgRibbonTeamBScoreDrake" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="104dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/zzz"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="167dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="247dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgRibbonTeamBScore" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="255dp"
    android:id="@+id/drakeBtnTeamB"
    android:background="@drawable/drake"
    android:layout_width="88dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="31dp"
    android:id="@+id/drakeBtnTeamA"
    android:background="@drawable/drake"
    android:layout_width="88dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="405dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
    android:id="@+id/baronBtnTeamA"
    android:background="@drawable/baron"
    android:layout_width="88dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="401dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="260dp"
    android:id="@+id/baronBtnTeamB"
    android:background="@drawable/baron"
    android:layout_width="88dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="138dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/victory"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/victoryImgTeamA"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="138dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/victory"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="227dp"
    android:id="@+id/victoryImageTeamB"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="340dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="296dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtDrakeScoreTeamB"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="24sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/fastScrollTextColor"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="339dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="71dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtDrakeScoreTeamA"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="24sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable" />

<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="496dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="71dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtBaronScoreTeamA"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="24sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable" />

<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="496dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="298dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtBaronScoreTeamB"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="24sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/fastScrollTextColor" />

<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="167dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtScoreTeamA"
    android:textSize="49sp"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable" />

<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="167dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="284dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtScoreTeamB"
    android:textSize="49sp"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/fastScrollTextColor" />

<TextView
    android:text="Team Blue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="145dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="251dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtTeamBlue"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Team Red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="145dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtTeamRed"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
```

Or you can find it here : http://pastebin.com/vjTkSGV0

Answer (score 0):

tools params are used only for the preview. So in the preview your layout would be fine, but not after compilation.

In [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-a-constraint) you need to define at least one horizontal constraint and one vertical constraint for your views.

For example:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imgViewMainBackground"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/lol"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```